# computing the exchange hash for ecdsa-sha2-nistp256

Tags: ssh, digital-signature

I am writing code for an SSH server and can not get past the Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange Reply part of the connection.  The client also closes the connection and says "Host Key does not match the signature supplied".

I am using putty as the client and a PIC micro-controller is running the server code.

From RFC 5656 [SSH ECC Algorithm Integration] :

"The hash H is formed by applying the algorithm HASH on a
   concatenation of the following:

```
  string   V_C, client's identification string (CR and LF excluded)
  string   V_S, server's identification string (CR and LF excluded)
  string   I_C, payload of the client's SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
  string   I_S, payload of the server's SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
  string   K_S, server's public host key
  string   Q_C, client's ephemeral public key octet string
  string   Q_S, server's ephemeral public key octet string
  mpint    K,   shared secret
```

"

the host key algorithm and key exchange algorithm is ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 and ecdh-sha2-nistp256 respectively.

referring to RFC 4251 for data type representations, as well as the source code in openSHH (openBSD) this is what I have concatenated.

1. 4 bytes for then length of V_C followed by V_C
2. 4 bytes for then length of V_S followed by V_S
3. 4 bytes for length of I_C followed by I_C (payload is from Message Code to the start of Random Padding)
4. 4 bytes for length of I_S followed by I_S (payload is from Message Code to the start of Random Padding)
5. 4 bytes for the length of K_S followed by K_S (for K_S I used the same group of bytes that is used to calculate the fingerprint)
6. 4 bytes for the length of Q_C followed by Q_C (i used the uncompressed string which has length of 65 - 04||X-coordinate||Y-coordinate)
7. 4 bytes for the length of Q_S followed by Q_S
8. 4 bytes for the length of K followed by K (length is 32 or 33 depending is the leading bit is set or not. If it is set then K is preceded by a 00 byte)

Once concatenated I hash it with SHA256 because I'm using NISTP256.  SHA256 outputs 32 bytes which is the size of the curve, so I take the whole SHA256 output and perform the signature algorithm on it.

I can never get the correct signature from my message concatenation.

I know my signature algorithm is correct because given the message hash output I can get the correct signature.
I know my shared secret is correct because I get the same output as online shared secret calculators.
I know the SHA256 is correct because I get the same result using online calculators.

This leads me to assume the error is in the concatenation of the exchange hash.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ECDSA signature generation is non-deterministic, i.e. part of the input is the hash and part of the input consists of random bytes. So whatever you do, you will always get a different signature. This is all right because signature verification will still work.

The only way to get a repeated signature is to mess with the random number generator (during testing, you don't want to sign two values using the same random number: you'd expose the private key!).

Comment: Yes, that is for the signature generation, and I am referring to the exchange hash generation.  Given the correct exchange hash I can produce the correct signature, but I cannot generate the correct exchange hash to use in the signature generation.